# How to check if a Textarea is empty in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

How do I check if a textarea contains nothing?

I tried with this code:

```
if(document.getElementById("field").value ==null)
{
    alert("debug");
    document.getElementById("field").style.display ="none";
 }
```

But it doesn't do what I expect.
I expect that it should appear a messagebox "debug" and that the textarea is not shown.

How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You wanna check if the value is `== ""`, not `NULL`.

```
if(document.getElementById("field").value == '')
{
    alert("debug");
    document.getElementById("field").style.display ="none";
}
```

**UPDATE**

A [working example](http://jsbin.com/ayeju)

And [another one using TRIM](http://jsbin.com/ayeju/2) in case you wanna make sure they don't post spaces

Implementation for TRIM()

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use following jQuery to escape white spaces as well.

```
if($("#YourTextAreaID").val().trim().length < 1)
{
    alert("Please Enter Text...");
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[There is a world of difference between null and empty !](http://p2p.wrox.com/classic-asp-databases/18161-difference-between-null-empty-string.html)**

Try this instead:

```
if(document.getElementById("field").value == "")
{
    alert("debug");
    document.getElementById("field").style.display ="none";
}
```