# how can I check if a TEXTAREA is filled on another page with a button?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am using classic ASP and I need to get a button to check if a TEXTAREA on another page is filled with the button. I can't seem to find anything about checking the textarea on another page. By the way I am kind of new to using javascript and ASP. I have tried many different codes but just can't seem to find the right one. This is what I have so far:

```
<SCRIPT language = "javascript">
function commentCheck(id)
{
    var empty = document.getElementById(id);
    if(empty.length<1)
    {
        window.alert ("This field cant be left empty");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: What do you mean by on another page?

Comment: For example, I am using one page to input hours but when I click okay to close it the ok button should verify that the comments page was filled out but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok, a better formulation would be: "How do I check if a textarea has been filled on client side". Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function commentCheck(id){
    var empty = document.getElementById(id);
    if(empty.value == ''){
        alert ("This field cant be left empty");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure it does, how do you call the function?

Comment: im calling to the function on the first page in a button through the onclick

Comment: so, your onclick should look something like this: `onclick="commentCheck('text');"` where `<textarea id="text"></textarea>`

Comment: it is still just closing the document instead of checking the box.

Comment: There must be something wrong elsewhere then, see this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476382/how-to-check-if-a-textarea-is-empty-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: OK that helped some, now it won't close though if the box is filled and it won't display the alert to fill it if it isn't filled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is a confirmation page. In this case, you'd need to check the POSTed data instead of the actual text area. Once the user has navigated away from your page, it's gone.

Also, this check would be done on the server side (your ASP code) and not in client side javascript.